# Laravel Echo Server not working properly with React Front End and Laravel Back End

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-echo

It appears that I have everything set up properly but for some reason I can't see my `console.log` that I have after listening for the event. I have two separate IPs, my back end in Laravel using MySQL for my DB (api.site.com) and my front end in React ([www.site.com](http://www.site.com)).

Here's my laravel-echo-server.json set up:

```
{
    "authHost": "https://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": ""
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

And I can see the event getting logged:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

Channel: chat.9722
Event: LeagueChatCreated
```

Here's my setup on the front end:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo/dist/echo";
import socketio from "socket.io-client";

const echo = new Echo({
    host: "https://api.site.com/socket.io", //might need to add this to the env
    broadcaster: "socket.io",
    client: socketio,
});

export default echo;
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    echo.channel("chat." + leagueId).listen("LeagueChatCreated", (ev) => {
        console.log("new request");
        chat.request();
    });

    return () => {
        echo.channel("chat." + leagueId).stopListening("LeagueChatCreated");
    };
}, []);
```

Before anyone says, are you sure `leagueId` matches with what you're broadcasting, yes it does.

I have set up a reverse proxy so that port 6001 points to /socket.io so that's not the issue. Especially since I'm seeing a response back from the network requests:

When hitting https://api.site.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nxqgsoi I'm getting a 200 and this response:

```
96:0{"sid":"S0tvcT6YLVhsRfniAAAO","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40
```

Can anyone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm currently out of ideas.

Here's how my Reverse Proxy is set up

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine on

<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
```

Comment: Have you checked if you are connecting to the ws in the networking tab of your browser? It is titled “WS”.

Comment: @Savlon the only thing I see in the network tab is hitting https://api.site.com/socket.io over and over so I'm not seeing a WS connection. But I do have a reverse proxy set up that could be getting around this. I edited my original question to include that above

Comment: @Savlon do you see an issue with what I'm doing with my reverse proxy set up? I needed a way to hit https along with port 6001 so that was my solution. Would I still need to be seeing ws hits in the network tab?

Comment: I wouldn’t think a reverse proxy would interfere with this. You need to check your WS tab because you shouldn’t be seeing api in that tab. Ensure your browser network tab is showing filters for the requests. The request should start with ‘ws:’

Comment: @Savlon ok, so I'm now getting hits in my network tab hitting ```wss://api.site.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket``` returning a 101 response code. Unfortunately, I'm still not seeing my console log whenever an event fires

Comment: Paste the connection response

Comment: So there's not necessarily a response like in other network connections. The tabs I see are Headers, Payload, Messages, Initiator, and Timing. Here's what's the response from the Messages tab ```0{"sid":"cSJ_2K7a9cK74JKgAAcR","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}```. Let me know if you're looking for something else

Comment: Is there any reason why you have not tacked on the port to the connection url? You are saying that your socket is on port 6001 but I don’t see it in your connection url.

Comment: That's what I have the reverse proxy set up for. Since I couldn't connect to port 6001 over https, I set /socket.io to point to port 6001

Comment: Ok sorry so how come you’re not using the port? Also, any reason for adding socketio as the client in the bootstrap file? You should have window.io = require(‘socket.io-client’);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242343/discussion-between-pbrune-and-savlon).

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings. Also, make sure you have your `.env` file variables set for your broadcast driver.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname
});
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
    "authHost": "https://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": ""
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env  NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    ... your own here
    },
    "dependencies": {
    ... your own here
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
        "laravel-echo-server": "^1.6.2",
        "socket.io-client": "2.3.0"
    }
}
```

**In a JS file that is loaded when someone logs in**

```
var channel = Echo.private(`users.${PUT_USER_ID_HERE}`)

channel.listen('.LeagueChatCreated', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

**In your php event file**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel("users.".$this->user->id);
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return "LeagueChatCreated";
}
```